# Bayes error and classifier error with 0-1 loss

Tags: self-study, bayesian, independence

I'm working on exercise 7.2 from Elements of Statistical Learning, and I'm confused about one particular part of the problem.

Let $Y \in \{0, 1\}$ and $\textrm{Pr}(Y = 1| X = x_0) = f(x_0)$. Let $\hat{G}(x) = I(\hat{f}(x) > 1/2)$ and ${G}(x) = I({f}(x) > 1/2)$ (the Bayes classifier). The error at a point $x_0$ with a 0-1 loss is given by:

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = \textrm{Pr}(Y \neq \hat{G}(x_0)|X = x_0)
$$

We need to show that:
$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = \textrm{Pr}(Y \neq {G}(x_0)|X = x_0) + |2f(x_0) - 1|\textrm{Pr}(\hat{G}(x_0) - G(x_0)| X = x_0)
$$

i.e., the error is the sum of the irreducible Bayes error plus estimation error.

However, any solution I've seen to the problem has involved expanding the term $\textrm{Pr}(Y \neq \hat{G}(x_0)|X = x_0)$ as follows:

$$
\textrm{Pr}(Y \neq \hat{G}(x_0)|X = x_0) = P(Y = G(x_0)|X = x_0)P(\hat{G}(x_0) \neq G(x_0)|X = x_0) + P(Y \neq G(x_0)|X = x_0)P(\hat{G}(x_0) = G(x_0)|X = x_0)
$$

I understand that there are only two possibilities, that either $Y = G$ or $Y \neq G$, but I don't see why that expansion follows. Isn't is implicitly assuming that $Y$ and $\hat{G}$ are independent, i.e., that if $G(x_0) = 1$, then $\textrm{Pr}(Y \neq 1,\, \hat{G}(x_0) = 0|X = x_0) = \textrm{Pr}(Y \neq 1|X = x_0)\textrm{Pr}(\hat{G}(x_0) = 1|X = x_0)$, which is not given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the original Friedman paper this question comes from clarified it. The classifiers are trained on a training set $T$ and the distributions of the $\hat{G}$ are conditional on $T$.

For the 0-1 loss, the risk or average error for a classifier (where the average is over $Y$ given any $x_0$ point) is:

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = E(\mathcal{L}(\hat{G}(x_0), Y)) = P(Y \neq \hat{G}(x_0)|X = x_0)
$$

When $\hat{G}(x_0) = 1$, $\textrm{Err}(x_0) = P(Y \neq 1 | X = x_0) = 1 - f(x_0)$. Similarly, when $\hat{G}(x_0) = 0$, $\textrm{Err}(x_0) = P(Y \neq 0 | X = x_0) = f(x_0)$. Thus,

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = f(x_0)\mathbf{1}(\hat{G}(x_0) = 0) + (1-f(x_0))\mathbf{1}(\hat{G}(x_0) = 1)
$$

So for every $x_0$, the only two possible values of the error are either $f(x_0)$ or $1 - f(x_0)$. The Bayes classifier achieves the Bayes error, the lowest possible error among classifiers. This means the Bayes error is:

$$
P(Y \neq G(x_0) | X = x_0) = \min(f(x_0), 1 - f(x_0))
$$

When $\hat{G}(x_0)$ corresponds to the Bayes classifier, it achieves the Bayes error. When the two do *not* coincide, the error of the classifier $\hat{G}(x_0)$ differs from the Bayes error and instead achieves error $\max(f(x_0), 1 - f(x_0))$. Thus, in this case, the difference between the errors is given by:

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) - \textrm{Err}(x_0)=\max(f(x_0), 1 - f(x_0)) - \min(f(x_0), 1 - f(x_0)) = |1 - 2f(x_0)|
$$

Thus,

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = |1 - 2f(x_0)|\mathbf{1}(\hat{G}(x_0) \neq G(x_0)) + P(Y \neq G(x_0)|X = x_0)
$$

Each classifier is implicitly conditioned on a training set $T$ that is used to train the classifier. Averaging over $T$ (which only appears with terms including $\hat{G}$), we get:

$$
\textrm{Err}(x_0) = |1 - 2f(x_0)|P(\hat{G}(x_0) \neq G(x_0)) + P(Y \neq G(x_0)|X = x_0)
$$